# How to minify a LESS file?

Tags: css, less, minify

Is it possible to minify LESS files in the same way as CSS files are minified by cssmin?

Are there any tools for this?

P.S. I don't need LESS files to be compiled into CSS. LESS files must remain LESS files because they are compiled at the client side by the less.js library. This is necessary to give users an option to override some of the variables used in LESS files and to create own styles.

Comment: Why would you want to minify the less file? The user does not need a less file.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more of an explanation of your flow would make this easier to understand. At the minute, no one understands why you need minified LESS files as they aren't rendered

Comment: @AndyHolmes I added an explanation :-)

Comment: So if they're being compiled by less.js, you need to run the output CSS through a minifier. Less.js may have a `compress` mode that will do the minifying

Comment: I want to reduce the size of less files which are being transfered. Minification of the files generated on the client-side wont bring anything. less.js runs in browser.

Comment: But I still don't get *why* you actually need to do this in the first place

Comment: @AndyHolmes compiling LESS at run-time enables flexibility which is not possible when using dev-time compilation.

Comment: @Andrej do you still need advice for your question?

Comment: @Axel, No, not any more.

Comment: If you meanwhile found a solution it would be really cool to share it (and give an answer on your own) anyway...

Comment: @Axel, sorry, I didn't solve it. But I think you can let a CSS minifies at least remove comments without much trouble.